# jquery-ui: creating a customized collapsablility function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create `<caption>` tags that are, by default, uncollapsed but which, as an "onclick" property, can be collapsed. I'd also like for the expansion/collapsing to animate very slightly—I'd like for them to "unfold" or transition vertically downward when expanding and to transition vertically upward when collapsing.

Currently I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $('.cv .collapsable').click(function() {
         $(this).next().toggle('slow');
         return false;
     }).next().hide();
});
```

However, this animates the *presentation of the content* within the collapsed `<caption>` rather than the unfolding of the parent element. I would really like to see the parent element expanding downward before the content of the element is displayed (or would be equally satisfied with the content of the element becoming visible as the element expands). Either way the issue is that the expansion is instantaneous and a bit jarring, whereas, once expanded, the content fades in gently.

Additionally, this function defaults to a collapsed state rather than an expanded one, and I need it to do the inverse. Basically, I want people to be able to collapse this to conserve screen real-estate if need be, but to otherwise have a normal and complete display of all the content between each `caption` tag. I'm sure this is very simple, I am complete *jquery* nub.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle (http://www.jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far?  It'd help us (or at least me) better understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/MgUmQ/2/) an attempt to do as you've asked; I've never used jsfiddle and, currently, it's not even performing as well as it does on my own machine (it's a localhost setup else I'd just link it). But really, this jsfiddle link includes all of the code that I'm using.  Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Updated [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MgUmQ/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a revised answer, based upon additional information added to the question and clarified by the comments made to this answer.

For starters, your items are already starting out visible, it's just that you're hiding them right away with the `.next.hide()`  code.

The animation you're describing doesn't match the one that you're using.  A toggle just does a straight hide/show animation by changing the opacity of the element slowly until it's gone.  However, what you're describing is a slide.  Take a look at jQuery's [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) functionality instead.

Also, tables don't hide gracefully, and you can't animate the hiding of just one item in a table very gracefully across all browsers.  As such, I'd recommend using span tags for your column headers.  Wrap your tables in a div (so that they will animate properly), and then wrap that all in another div, like so:

```
<div id="table1">
  <span class='collapsable'>Title 1</span>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="table2">
  <span class='collapsable'>Title 2</span >
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
           <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

On to the javascript, it's pretty simple, just change the toggle to toggleSlide, and update the selectors, remove the initial hide, and voila!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.collapsable').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/cnvkg/)

### -

### -

Here's the original answer, left here in case anyone stumbles across this looking for the issue I first thought you were having:

To start, your HTML isn't valid.  Having multiple THead's inside of a table is invalid.  THead's are intended to be a column heading.  As such, it can't live as a child as tbody.  Take a look at the w3c standards for tables: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

For what you're trying to accomplish, you will need to use multiple tables.  It appears as though you're attempting to use the thead's as a caption.  For this, you should use a `<caption>` instead.

Also, you're not actually using jquery-ui (at least not in this bit of code), there's no reason to include all of the jquery-ui css in the fiddle.  (If you were using it, you may want to consider adding a reference to Google's CDN hosted css file in the Manage Resources section).

All that said, I think this fiddle here is what you're aiming for: http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/VbqaX/

Comment: Thanks on the HTML; I just couldn't find a resource link for the CSS. But, the solution you've provided is exactly what I started with—it doesn't address anything in my original question, because I was already able to produce what you've got in that fiddle (though my fiddle example, as stated above, does less than the original document on my setup—I've just never used fiddle). What I need is a) the function to default to expanded status, instead of collapsed, and b) animation of the collapsing/expanding, rather than animating the presentation of the content after an expand has occurred.

Comment: I've re-written my question, however, to better explain my dilemma because my ignorance on the topic is probably causing ambiguities. I do appreciate the attempt at assistance!

Comment: Updated answer based upon the revised info.  I'm pretty sure it's doing now what you were asking for.

Comment: My hero, perfect. Thank you both for the code itself and for the time spent explaining it. This is precisely and exactly what I was looking for.